# Best practice for loading different media on orientation change

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design, frontend

I've been doing a lot of Googling on this topic and I havent been able to find anything helpful.

I've been given the task of creating a mobile website based on designs that my design team came up with. One of the features they came up with is to have different versions of images based on the orientation of your device. So for each image that they want to do this with you have two versions:

```
image1Portrait.jpg
image1Landscape.jpg
```

I was thinking of combining the two images into one image that would essentially be Sprite-esk. When the onorientationchange event fires, I'd change the css and the image would essentially move over and display the correct version.

My other option is to simply swap out the source of the image for the landscape version. I am not in favor of this though as you will have to wait for it to download.

My question is this: Is there any best practice for doing this sort of thing? Like I said, I've been Googling, but I havent found anything helpful.

Comment: Your first option is a bad idea (my opinion only) - you're essentially loading both images (via combining them into one) when the user only wants one of them. Why make them download data they may never need?

Comment: Yes I agree, I just haven't landed on a better option just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries are what you need for this:

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* Portrait styles */
}

/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Landscape styles */
}
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you. A second requirement to these images in that they will be "scrollable", where you can swipe left and right and scroll through a gallery of images ([See example](http://codecanyon.net/item/royalslider-touchenabled-jquery-image-gallery/461126?ref=Semenov) )

Would media queries work with something like this?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Flexslider for that. It's a fully responsive & touch enabled slider: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: Just wanted to throw it out there, but PhotoSwipe is quite handy as well.